# How to create a Horizontal view from vertical table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, view, sybase

I have the following table defination

```
table Rec
{
integer attrib_id
integer attrib_value,
integer unique_id
}
```

The attributes have another mapping as follows
table attributes

```
{
  integer attrib_id,
  integer group_id
}
```

I have around 20 attribute id allocated to different group ids.
It is possible that a attribute id is not present for a group_id in table Rec.
I created the following view  for a specific group id as follows-

```
create view group as 
  select tr1.attrib_value as "Name", 
         tr2.attrib_value as "Age", 
         tr3.attrib_value as "Sex"
    from Rec tr1, 
         Rec tr2, 
         Rec tr3
   where tr1.unique_id = tr2.unique_id
     and tr2.unique_id = tr3.unique_id
     and tr1.unique_id = tr3.unique_id
     and tr1.attrib_id = 1
     and tr2.attrib_id = 2
     and tr3.attrib_id = 3
```

I want to create a horizontal mapping from vertical table list.
The problem is that it is possible that there may not a specific attribute in `Rec` table. So there clause fails.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Create a table with all possible attributes that may be, then left join the attributes table to it.